# Connect to Sony Xperia M Dual with adb/fastboot

Tags: adb, fastboot

I want to ask how to install custom rom on Xperia M Dual

I had tried adb and fastboot command in cmd but it shows waiting for device..

Help me please I'm too frustrated

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't install the proper usb drivers. Easiest way I can recommend: Boot a linux live system, install fastboot and adb and execute the commands as root.

Comment: But I'm running on win7 64 bit

Comment: That's why you should try a *live* system which does not require installation. Ohterwise, try to properly install the usb drivers for windows 7, without them your device will not be detected.